# Time synchronisation service on UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, time

I have a VPS running Debian.  The time that it reports from the `date` command is two minutes fast.

Is there a service that I can install that will keep the time correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ntp" service handles date/time synchronization.

Comment: NTP synch isn't so helpful on a virtual machine.  you'd run `ntpd` on the host OS, then synch the guest via the virtualization tech's builtin methods.

Answer (score 0):

ntpd works wonders unless the virtual cmos clock is being set by the hypervisor, in which case the time on the host machine needs to be set by the sysadmin, nothing you can do.